# Не работает ajaxStop и ajaxStart для ajax запроса

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Суть такова: Есть ajax-запрос. 
Пример:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    global: true,
});
$.ajax({
   'method': 'POST',
   'data': requestData,
   'url': link,
   'dataType': 'json',
   beforeSend: function () {
       if (spin) {
           showSpinner();
       }
   },
   complete: function () {
       if (spin) {
           hideSpinner();
       }
   },
});
```

Он находится в одном скрипте. Я пытаюсь получить событие его выполнения так:

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {  console.log('hello');  });
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {  console.log('hello');  });
```

Но в консоль ничего не выводится. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: А ваш ajax, вообще, выполняется?

Comment: Конечно, и если я внедрю свою функцию в блок success , то она отработает, но трогать сам ajax напрямую нельзя, это плагин wordpress и при следующем обновлении всё слетит...

Comment: Попробуйте заменить `ajaxSetup()` на `$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options ) { options.global = true; })`

Comment: Не помогает :( Может вам больше нужно информации?
Скрипты находятся в двух разных файлах. Ajax запрос находится в функции и она выполняется внутри того файла, а ловить всё это дело я пытаюсь из другого файла.